# How disable debuger on chrome webdriver in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, debugging, webdriver

anybody know how to disable a debugger/logging in chrome webdriver in Python 3.6 ?

[image]

I'm trying following code and it isn't working.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-login-animations")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, service_log_path='NUL', service_args=["--verbose", r"--log-path=D:\qc1.log"])
```

Python ver.: **3.6.1**

Chrome Browser ver.: **62.0.3202.94 (64bit)**

Webdriver ver.: **2.33**

OS: **Win10 (64bit)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this `chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")` to shut the logging.